# Slime-edit-definition to functions defined in top level let form?

Tags: common-lisp, slime

Are there any ways to jump to functions defined in top level let form by slime-edit-definition?

For example below, I want to jump to the head of (defin foo ...) form, not that of top level (let ...) form:

```
(let (var)
  (defun foo ()
    var)))
```

Comment: It might be better to ask such very specific questions on the corresponding SLIME mailing list.

Comment: Thanks, I will ask to SLIME mailing list